# Blank process name for OSX Cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa, macos, process, osx-leopard

I'm developing an OSX application ([Clarke](http://tomtaylor.co.uk/projects/clarke/)) that runs with LSUIElement set (system menu only - no tray icon, doesn't appear in cmd-tab).

It works totally fine, but someone just pointed out that it has a blank process name in the Activity Monitor listing. Just says nothing. Everything else in there has a name. Even other apps running at LSUIElement.

I've tried to search around the web, but I can't spot anyone talking about this. What on earth should I be looking for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out I had the CFBundleDisplayName key present, but empty. That solves it.

Comment: Peter actually gave you this answer. You should give credit to him by up-voting his answer and/or accepting it rather than leaving the answer open and adding your own answer (which, in fact, is the same as Peter's suggestion).

Comment: Not exactly. CFBundleName and CFBundleDisplayName aren't the same thing.

Comment: Ah, good point, Peter! I was reading too quickly and missed it. In any event, you should accept your answer, then Tom :)

Answer (score 5):

Wild guess: Check the CFBundleName in your Info.plist. Make sure that's set and not empty.